# What is the correct group for ConfigMaps in a Kustomize patch?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

In general, how can I get the group name for any type of resource?

And in particular, what should I use for group here:

```yaml
  - path: cm.patch.yaml
    target:
      kind: ConfigMap
      group: ""         # <------
      version: v1
      name: my-confif
```

Is it the empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the [Kubernetes API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/).

If you look at, for example, [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/storage-class-v1/), it says at the top of the page

> `apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1`

So for this object, the group is `storage.k8s.io`, the version is `v1`, and the kind is `StorageClass`.

The [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/config-map-v1/) page says just

> `apiVersion: v1`

This is in the "core" group, and an empty string as you have it in the question is correct.